# Python, Apache, Playwright, mod_wsgi, and Flask: OSError: Apache/mod_wsgi log object is not associated with a file descriptor

Tags: python, apache, flask, mod-wsgi, playwright

I'm a beginner with running websites, but I have a GoDaddy VPS and Domain Name, that I'm trying to run a Flask website on. This Flask website uses Playwright to scrape data from a webpage, and send it to the Flask app running over HTTPS. However, when I try and run `p = sync_playwright().start()`, I get an internal server error on the website. I'm using mod_wsgi to configure the Flask server.

I've checked all paths and they seem to be correct, main.py and other files are owned by the www-data user. My mod_wsgi file is below:

```
#!/usr/bin/python
import sys
sys.path.insert(0,"/var/www/jimmyscompany.top")
from main import app as application
```

My apache2 sites-enabled file is:

```
<IfModule mod_ssl.c>
<VirtualHost *:443>
    # The ServerName directive sets the request scheme, hostname and port that
    # the server uses to identify itself. This is used when creating
    # redirection URLs. In the context of virtual hosts, the ServerName
    # specifies what hostname must appear in the request's Host: header to
    # match this virtual host. For the default virtual host (this file) this
    # value is not decisive as it is used as a last resort host regardless.
    # However, you must set it for any further virtual host explicitly.
    ServerName www.jimmyscompany.top

    ServerAdmin myemail.com
    DocumentRoot /var/www/jimmyscompany.top

    # Available loglevels: trace8, ..., trace1, debug, info, notice, warn,
    # error, crit, alert, emerg.
    # It is also possible to configure the loglevel for particular
    # modules, e.g.
    #LogLevel info ssl:warn

    WSGIDaemonProcess jimmyscompany.top user=www-data group=www-data threads=5 home=/var/www/jimmyscompany.top/
    WSGIScriptAlias / /var/www/jimmyscompany.top/jimmyscompany.top.wsgi
    <directory /var/www/jimmyscompany.top/>
    WSGIProcessGroup jimmyscompany.top
    WSGIApplicationGroup %{GLOBAL}
    WSGIScriptReloading On            
             
    Order deny,allow
    Allow from all
    Require all granted 
     
    </directory>

    ErrorLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/error.log
    CustomLog ${APACHE_LOG_DIR}/access.log combined

    # For most configuration files from conf-available/, which are
    # enabled or disabled at a global level, it is possible to
    # include a line for only one particular virtual host. For example the
    # following line enables the CGI configuration for this host only
    # after it has been globally disabled with "a2disconf".
    #Include conf-available/serve-cgi-bin.conf


ServerName jimmyscompany.top
Include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-apache.conf
ServerAlias www.jimmyscompany.top
SSLCertificateFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jimmyscompany.top/fullchain.pem
SSLCertificateKeyFile /etc/letsencrypt/live/jimmyscompany.top/privkey.pem
</VirtualHost>
</IfModule>
```

I have checked and all of the paths are correct, and valid. The related error logs are: (from /var/log/apache2/error.log)

```
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:10.359598 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 14167:tid 139928677414784] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:10.359659 2024] [core:notice] [pid 14167:tid 139928677414784] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:31.683136 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14168:tid 139928624473664] [remote my_ip:54194] mod_wsgi (pid=14168): Failed to exec Python script file '/var/www/jimmyscompany.top/jimmyscompany.top.wsgi'.
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:31.683184 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14168:tid 139928624473664] [remote my_ip:54194] mod_wsgi (pid=14168): Exception occurred processing WSGI script '/var/www/jimmyscompany.top/jimmyscompany.top.wsgi'.
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:31.683314 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14168:tid 139928624473664] [remote my_ip:54194] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:31.683331 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14168:tid 139928624473664] [remote my_ip:54194]   File "/var/www/jimmyscompany.top/jimmyscompany.top.wsgi", line 4, in <module>
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:31.683334 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14168:tid 139928624473664] [remote my_ip:54194]     from main import create_app
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:31.683343 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14168:tid 139928624473664] [remote my_ip:54194] ImportError: cannot import name 'create_app' from 'main' (/var/www/jimmyscompany.top/main.py)
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:50.266894 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 14167:tid 139928677414784] AH00492: caught SIGWINCH, shutting down gracefully
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:53.631854 2024] [core:warn] [pid 14167:tid 139928677414784] AH00045: child process 14169 still did not exit, sending a SIGTERM
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:54.771998 2024] [mpm_event:notice] [pid 14253:tid 140356138370944] AH00489: Apache/2.4.52 (Ubuntu) OpenSSL/3.0.2 mod_wsgi/4.9.0 Python/3.10 configured -- resuming normal operations
[Thu Feb 22 09:54:54.772069 2024] [core:notice] [pid 14253:tid 140356138370944] AH00094: Command line: '/usr/sbin/apache2'
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904707 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794] [2024-02-22 09:55:05,903] ERROR in app: Exception on /login/finish [POST]
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904742 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794] Traceback (most recent call last):
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904744 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 1463, in wsgi_app
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904747 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     response = self.full_dispatch_request()
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904749 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 872, in full_dispatch_request
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904751 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     rv = self.handle_user_exception(e)
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904764 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 870, in full_dispatch_request
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904767 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     rv = self.dispatch_request()
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904769 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/flask/app.py", line 855, in dispatch_request
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904771 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     return self.ensure_sync(self.view_functions[rule.endpoint])(**view_args)  # type: ignore[no-any-return]
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904774 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/var/www/jimmyscompany.top/main.py", line 123, in finish_login
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904776 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     if sentralify(user, check_login=True) == True:
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904778 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/sentralify/__init__.py", line 49, in sentralify
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904780 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     p = sync_playwright().start() # Start a playwright instance
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904782 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/playwright/sync_api/_context_manager.py", line 84, in start
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904784 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     return self.__enter__()
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904786 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/playwright/sync_api/_context_manager.py", line 77, in __enter__
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904789 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     dispatcher_fiber.switch()
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904791 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/playwright/sync_api/_context_manager.py", line 56, in greenlet_main
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904793 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     self._loop.run_until_complete(self._connection.run_as_sync())
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904795 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/lib/python3.10/asyncio/base_events.py", line 649, in run_until_complete
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904797 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     return future.result()
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904799 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 267, in run_as_sync
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904801 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     await self.run()
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904804 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/playwright/_impl/_connection.py", line 276, in run
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904806 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     await self._transport.connect()
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904808 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/playwright/_impl/_transport.py", line 135, in connect
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904810 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     raise exc
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904812 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/playwright/_impl/_transport.py", line 128, in connect
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904818 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     stderr=_get_stderr_fileno(),
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904820 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.10/dist-packages/playwright/_impl/_transport.py", line 39, in _get_stderr_fileno
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904822 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794]     return sys.stderr.fileno()
[Thu Feb 22 09:55:05.904824 2024] [wsgi:error] [pid 14254:tid 140356077037120] [remote my_ip:53794] OSError: Apache/mod_wsgi log object is not associated with a file descriptor.
```

To summarise: When I try and start playwright, I get an error from mod_wsgi. If you need more code information, please just ask!